# showModalDialog(externalAppHtml, ...) spawning a new window in IE

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, window, showmodaldialog

I already looked at [showModalDialog; Opens a New Window in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200710/showmodaldialog-opens-a-new-window-in-ie) thread but that solution didn't work for me.

I have an angularjs file and I am using showModalDialog to open an external app's html page in a modal like below

```
var cUrl2 = "http://localhost/cc/CollectionLog.do?customerNbr=" + collectionItem.borrowerId + "&dealNbr=" +
            collectionItem.loanId + "&coll=log&requestBean.moduleStatus=newcsotitleLoan&fromCAS=yes";
window.showModalDialog(cUrl2, window, "title:" + windowName + ";dialogWidth:" + winWidth + ";dialogHeight:" +
            winHeight + ";center:yes");
```

I have already tried putting

```
<base target="_self" />
```

but it still spawns another window after opening the dialog. How can I fix this. Is there a better way to open a modal window with html provided by another app(Does it matter?). Is there anything else specific in that external app's html that I should look for and fix?

Comment: You're using an obsolete browser API. [`showModalDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog): "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time." "Support has been removed in Chrome 37." "Mozilla has announced that it will remove support for this method."

Comment: We are still using IE9. Though we have plans to move onto IE11 we have a requirement to be backward compatible with IE9. Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var winHeight = $(window).height() - 100;
var winWidth = $(window).width() - 200;
var windowOptions = 'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=' + winWidth +
            ',height=' + winHeight + ',left=100,top=100';
cUrl = xxxx.html
window.open(cUrl, "win", windowOptions);
```

I used window.open instead and it worked. Perfect alternative for my issue.